# How would you Alter a SQL column to use a stored procedure to calculate specific information

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm delving into SQL at the moment and I'm struggling to find information on how to Alter a tables column to use a stored procedure to automatically declare a value in the specified field(Probably made no sense...), in this case my stored procedure works and calculates the age of a person and truncates it into an integer.

My problem is with the code that follows.

```
DECLARE @age int 
ALTER TABLE [dbo].Users 
ALTER COLUMN [age] AS getAge [dateOfBirth], @age OUTPUT
```

I'm getting a syntax error around the 'AS', however everything i try seems to get a syntax error somewhere in that small block.

My question is : What is wrong with that code? and how can i fix it?

Regards,
SBeynon.

Comment: Do you want to rename the column?

Comment: Do you want to update `age` column with the value returned from stored procedure  `getAge ` ?

Comment: Are you trying to perform a one-time update query, or alter the table schema such that the `age` column is a calculated column?

Comment: I'm trying to update the 'age' column so that it becomes a calculated column as you said alroc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think, you can use a stored procedure for computed columns. Instead why don't you use UDF

eg.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].FunctionName(....


ALTER TABLE [dbo].Users 
   ALTER COLUMN [age] AS [dbo].FunctionName(ColumnName);
```

Comment: This does exactly what i was trying to accomplish, thanks for your time and help.